# c# dictionary inside a list

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I need to use a dictionary inside this list

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> People= new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

So far I have tried to populate it with this

```
People[0] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
People[0].Add("ID number", "1");
People[0].Add("Name", "John");
```

and display it to the console

```
for (int i = 0; i < People.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(People[i]["ID number"]);
    Console.WriteLine(People[i]["Name"]);
}
```

I got 
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error on run, any fixes?

Comment: `"ID Number"` vs `"ID number"` - typo or key missmatch

Comment: You should consider creating a `Person` class instead of your current data structure.

Comment: @fubo thanks for mentioning, its a typo

Comment: Collections of collections allways make me feel sceptic. I agree Rand you should create a class that represents that data-structure.

Comment: `People[0]` whereas your list is empty, of course it will throw an exception ..? To add item to a IList use Add method :`People.Add(...)` and yes this structure seems really weird :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Add` to add items to a `List` in C#.

Change your code to:

```
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> People= new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    People.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
    People[0].Add("ID Number", "1");
    People[0].Add("Name", "John");
    for (int i = 0; i < People.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(People[i]["ID Number"]);
        Console.WriteLine(People[i]["Name"]);
    }
```

However, I'd recommend creating a class to represent `Person`:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

And doing

```
var people = new List<Person>();
var person = new Person("1", "John");
people.Add(person);
for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].ID);
    Console.WriteLine(people[i].Name);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @haldo

Comment: @FakeCaleb thanks, updated now :)

Comment: @Florian - no cheating, let him fix it himself :)

Comment: @RandRandom oopsie! maybe you can replace `List<Person>` by `var` since you assign a `new List<Person>` this is pretty clear and lowercase `P` of `People`:p

Comment: @Florian - don't get picky now :D

Answer (score 1):

```
People.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

Don´t you need to add the first entry in the List first?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
People[0] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

with

```
People.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

You get a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because you access a not existing item.